# Listening socket backlog size. I can not understand the wording of a manpage

Tags: sockets, freebsd, kqueue

My `man` pages for `kqueue` give me the following:

> ```
>  EVFILT_READ         Takes a descriptor as the identifier, and returns
>                      whenever there is data available to read.  The
>                      behavior of the filter is slightly different
>                      depending on the descriptor type.
>
>                      Sockets
>                          Sockets which have previously been passed to
>                          listen() return when there is an incoming
>                          connection pending.  data contains the size of
>                          the listen backlog.
> ```

The question follows, is above backlog value equals the number of total backlog size, or, the value equals the actual backlog size, as the event returns to a user?

Answer (score 0):

It equals to the actual listen queue size. Yes, the actual connection(`accept`) may not succeed. But, I do not think that the listen queue size will change while `accept` calls being made. I'm not so competent in reading source code, but I can do a simple logic:

```
1. There is a list of connections waiting to be accepted.
2. The connection may either succeed or fail.
 3. If the connection succeeds, it does not change a queue size.
 4. If the connection fails, the `accept` function returns the reason.
5. From above, the status of a connection will not change actual
   listen backlog. 
   You also can made this logic from error codes of `accept` function. If the system removes a connection, the accept returns an error.
```